# How can I use Bonjour on iOS to let other devices connected to my iPhones hotspot know the ip address and port of the server my iOS app is hosting?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bonjour

I have created an iOS app that hosts a UDP Server. It doesn't seem possible for me to know the IP address of the server before hand. I use this function to get the IP Address:

// Get IP Addresses

```
void getIPAddresses(std::map<std::string, std::string>& addresses) {
    struct ifaddrs *interfaces = NULL;
    struct ifaddrs *temp_addr = NULL;
    // Retrieve the current interfaces - returns 0 on success
    int success = getifaddrs(&interfaces);
    if (success == 0) {
        // Loop through linked list of interfaces
        temp_addr = interfaces;
        while (temp_addr != NULL) {
            if (temp_addr->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET) {
                // Check if interface is en0 which is the wifi connection on the iPhone
                addresses[temp_addr->ifa_name] = inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)temp_addr->ifa_addr)->sin_addr);
            }
            temp_addr = temp_addr->ifa_next;
        }
    }
    // Free memory
    freeifaddrs(interfaces);
}
```

As can be seen this function returns an number of IP addresses and without trial and error it doesn't seem possible to determine which IP address the server actually receives UDP packets on.

Is there some way I can do this better using Bonjour ? The devices that connect to my UDP Server can do so because my iPhone acts as a Wifi Hotspot (I share the SSID and Password to the devices in advance).

EDIT:

It seems that whenever I create an Wifi Hotpspot, the UDP Server is accessible on the interface called "Bridge100". So I know what the iP address is. How can I use Bonjour so that other devices connected to my iPhones Wifi Hotspot can know the iP address of my udp server ?

Comment: You should be just able to advertise an `NSNetService`. It will advertise on all interfaces and then listening clients will discover it.

Comment: @Paulw11 can you explain with more details please?

Comment: See https://github.com/ugurtemiz/ios-bonjour/blob/master/ios-bonjour/ViewController.swift ; this is advertising a tcp service but you can advertise a UDP service.